# Proving the inequality $\frac{ab}{\sqrt{c^2+3}}+\frac{bc}{\sqrt{a^2+3}}+\frac{ca}{\sqrt{b^2+3}}\leq \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c>0$ and $ab + bc + ca = 3$, prove that:
$\frac{ab}{\sqrt{c^2+3}}+\frac{bc}{\sqrt{a^2+3}}+\frac{ca}{\sqrt{b^2+3}}\leq \frac{3}{2}$

Thank you.

Comment: Add that to your question to improve its quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong! Try $c=0$. We need to prove that  $\sqrt3\leq\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: oh, thank you i got it. But what if $a,b,c>0$?

Comment: @TNQ So try $c\rightarrow0^+$ or try $c=0.000001$.